# Solving the tetrahedron given the outward normal vectors of the faces and the area of one face

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

Inspired by [this recent MSE problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491270/proving-the-centroid-property-and-the-existence-of-corresponding-convex-polyhe) I am working on the problem of solving the tetrahedron, given outward normal vectors to its faces, and the area of one face.

That is, I want to find all the edges of the tetrahedron given the above-mentioned information.

A detailed solution on how to do this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a tetrahedron with concurrent edges $a$, $b$, $c$ opposite respective edges $d$, $e$, $f$. Define faces $W:=\triangle def$ (whose area we'll consider known), $X:=\triangle dbc$, $Y:=\triangle aec$, $Z:=\triangle abf$, and let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ be the dihedral angles along respective edges.

[image]

Let $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ be the known unit outward normals to faces $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}
\cos A = -y\cdot z \qquad \cos B &= -z\cdot x \qquad \cos C = -x\cdot y \\
\cos D = -w\cdot x \qquad \cos E &= -w\cdot y \qquad \cos F = -w\cdot z
\end{align}$$
So, all dihedral angles are known.

[image]

Let $O$ be the vertex opposite $W$. Project $O$ to $O'$ in that face, and project $O'$ to $O''$ on (possibly-extended) edge $d$. Then $\angle OO''O'$ matches dihedral angle $D$. Defining $h:=|OO''|$, we can write $|OO'|=h\sin D$ and $|O'O''|=h\cos D$. The latter is the altitude to base $d$ of a subtriangle of face $W$; this subtriangle has area $\frac12dh\cos D$. But $h$ itself is the altitude to base $d$ of face $X$, so that $X=\frac12dh$; thus, the subtriangle has area $X\cos D$. Likewise $O'$ determines subtriangles along edges $e$ and $f$ with areas $Y\cos E$ and $Z \cos F$; thus, we have a decomposition of face $W$:
$$W = X \cos D + Y \cos E + Z \cos F$$
(The reader can verify that this makes sense even with obtuse dihedral angles.) In a similar fashion, abbreviating $\cos\theta$ as $\ddot{\theta}$, we have
$$\begin{align}
X &= W\ddot{D} + Y \ddot{C} + Z \ddot{B} \\[4pt]
Y &= X\ddot{C} + W \ddot{E} + Z \ddot{A} \\[4pt]
Z &= X\ddot{B} + Y \ddot{A} + W \ddot{F}
\end{align}$$
Solving the linear system for $X$, $Y$, $Z$ gives
$$\begin{align}
X &= W\;\frac{\ddot{A}\;(-\ddot{A}\ddot{D}+\ddot{B}\ddot{E}+\ddot{C}\ddot{F}) 
+ \ddot{D}+\ddot{B}\ddot{F}+\ddot{C}\ddot{E}}{1-2\ddot{A} \ddot{B} \ddot{C} - \ddot{A}^2-\ddot{B}^2-\ddot{C}^2}\\[8pt]
Y &= W\;\frac{\ddot{B}\;(\phantom{-}\ddot{A}\ddot{D}-\ddot{B}\ddot{E}+\ddot{C}\ddot{F}) 
+ \ddot{E}+\ddot{C}\ddot{D}+\ddot{A}\ddot{F}}{1-2\ddot{A} \ddot{B} \ddot{C} - \ddot{A}^2-\ddot{B}^2-\ddot{C}^2}\\[8pt]
Z &= W\;\frac{\ddot{C}\;(\phantom{-}\ddot{A}\ddot{D}+\ddot{B}\ddot{E}-\ddot{C}\ddot{F}) + \ddot{F}+\ddot{A}\ddot{E}+\ddot{B}\ddot{D}}{1-2\ddot{A} \ddot{B} \ddot{C} - \ddot{A}^2-\ddot{B}^2-\ddot{C}^2}
\end{align}$$
So, all face-areas are known. Then also volume, via this formula:
$$V^4 = \frac{4}{81} X^2 Y^2 Z^2 \left(\; 1-2\ddot{A} \ddot{B} \ddot{C} - \ddot{A}^2-\ddot{B}^2-\ddot{C}^2\;\right)$$

We can also calculate volume from face $W$ and altitude $OO'$:
$$V = \frac13 W h\sin D = \frac13 W\frac{2X}{d}\sin D \qquad\to\qquad
d = \frac23 \frac{WX}{V}\sin D$$

So, edge-length $d$ is known. Likewise,
$$
a = \frac23\frac{YZ}{V}\sin A \qquad 
b = \frac23\frac{ZX}{V}\sin B \qquad
c = \frac23\frac{XY}{V}\sin C$$
$$e = \frac23\frac{WY}{V}\sin E \qquad
f = \frac23\frac{WZ}{V}\sin F$$
The tetrahedron is solved. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the vertices are $\vec{v}_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $\vec{v}_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$, $\vec{v}_3 = (x_3, y_3, z_3)$, and $\vec{v}_4 = (x_4, y_4, z_4)$.  Then, the four outwards-facingnd normal vectors are
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{n}_{123} &= (\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1) \times (\vec{v}_3 - \vec{v}_1) \\
\vec{n}_{124} &= -(\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1) \times (\vec{v}_4 - \vec{v}_1) \\
\vec{n}_{134} &= (\vec{v}_3 - \vec{v}_1) \times (\vec{v}_4 - \vec{v}_1) \\
\vec{n}_{234} &= -(\vec{v}_3 - \vec{v}_2) \times (\vec{v}_4 - \vec{v}_2) \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\times$ denotes vector cross product, and only the *direction* of the normal vector matters.  Their magnitudes are twice the area of the corresponding face, i.e.
$$A_{123} = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \vec{n}_{123} \right\rVert, ~ ~ ~
A_{124} = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \vec{n}_{124} \right\rVert, ~ ~ ~
A_{134} = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \vec{n}_{134} \right\rVert, ~ ~ ~
A_{234} = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \vec{n}_{234} \right\rVert$$
because the magnitude of a cross product of two vectors is the area of the corresponding parallelogram, which in turn has exactly twice the area of a triangle with two of the edges matching the two vectors.

I would start by scaling the given normal vectors so that their magnitude matches twice the area of that face; if $\vec{\eta}$ is one of the given normal vectors (with unspecified magnitude), and $\lambda$ the area of that face, then use
$$\vec{n} = 2 \lambda \frac{\vec{\eta}}{\left\lVert\vec{\eta}\right\rVert} = 2 \lambda \frac{\vec{\eta}}{\sqrt{\vec{\eta}\cdot\vec{\eta}}}$$
for the corresponding normal vector; it embodies all the data needed for that particular face.

Then, because of how we chose the magnitude, $\eqref{1}$ is exactly true.

Next, I would arbitrarily choose the first vertex to be at origin, $\vec{v}_1 = \vec{0} = (0, 0, 0)$, as the normals or the areas do not define its location; it can be translated if need be later on.

At this point, we have a system of nine unknowns, and $3 \times 4 = 12$ linear equations.  Write them out component-wise, i.e.
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
x_{123} &= (y_2 - y_1)(z_3 - z_1) - (z_2 - z_1)(y_3 - y_1) \\
y_{123} &= (z_2 - z_1)(x_3 - x_1) - (x_2 - x_1)(z_3 - z_1) \\
z_{123} &= (x_2 - x_1)(y_3 - y_1) - (y_2 - y_1)(x_3 - x_1) \\
 ~ & ~ ~ \vdots \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $\vec{n}_{123} = (x_{123}, y_{123}, z_{123})$, and start solving.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Number the faces $1, 2, 3, 4$.  The corresponding unit normal vectors are $ n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4 $

Assume the area of the first face $F_1$ is known, then from Minkowski's theorem we know that

$ F_1 n_1 + F_2 n_2 + F_3 n_3 + F_4 n_4 = 0 $

Which is a linear system of $3 $ equations in the $3$
unknowns $F_2, F_3, F_4$ and can be solved readily.

Now we have $F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4  $ all known.

Labelling the edges from the faces it lies on, we have

$F_1$ contains edges  $e_{12}, e_{13}, e_{14} $

etc.

Define the unit vectors $w_{ij} = \dfrac{n_i \times n_j} {\| n_i \times n_j \| } $

Then
$ e_{ij} $ is along the unit vector $w_{ij}$

Now

$F_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \ e_{12} e_{13} \ \| w_{12} \times w_{13} \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \ e_{12} \ e_{14} \ \| w_{12} \times w_{14} \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \ e_{13} \ e_{14} \ \| w_{13} \times w_{14} \| $

It follows that

$\dfrac{1}{e_{14}}  \| w_{12} \times w_{13} \| = \dfrac{1}{e_{13}} \| w_{12} \times w_{14} \| = \dfrac{1}{e_{12}} \| w_{13} \times w_{14} \| = \dfrac{1}{t_1} $

Which gives

$(e_{12}, e_{13}, e_{14}) = t_1 ( \| w_{13} \times w_{14} \|, \| w_{12} \times w_{14} \| , | w_{12} \times w_{13} \| ) $

now we can solve for $t_1$ because

$F_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \  t_1^2 \ \| w_{12} \times w_{13} \| \ \| w_{13} \times w_{14} \| \ \| w_{12} \times  w_{14} \| $

so $t_1$ is now known, and so are $e_{12}, e_{13}, e_{14}$.

Similarly,

$F_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \ t_2^2 \ \| w_{21} \times w_{23} \| \ \| w_{21} \times w_{24} \| \ \| w_{23} \times w_{24} \| $

hence , $e_{23}, e_{24} $ can be found as follows:

$(e_{23}, e_{24}) = t_2 ( \| w_{21} \times w_{24} \| , \| w_{21} \times w_{23} \| )$

and finally,

$F_3 = \dfrac{1}{2} \ t_3^2 \ \| w_{31} \times w_{32} \| \ \| w_{31} \times w_{34} \| \ \| w_{32} \times w_{34} \| $

From which,

$e_{34} = t_3 \ \| w_{31} \times w_{32} \|$

Thus, all the edge lengths have been found.